# iOS to PHP Image upload

Tags: php, ios

I am trying to upload an image to my server from IOS7 via php5.

iOS Code

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://<domain>/conAPI/imageAPI.php";
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(venueImageView.image);

NSMutableURLRequest *requestImage = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [requestImage setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [requestImage setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[requestImage addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedimage\"; filename=\"V%@.png\"\r\n",[userDictioanry objectForKey:@"user_id"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestImage setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestImage returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Image Return String: %@", returnString);
```

and my php

```
ini_set('log_errors',1);
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/memberImages/';
print_r($_FILES);
$file = $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (file_exists($uploaddir) && is_writable($uploaddir)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo 'DONE '.$file;
    }else {
        echo "error ".$_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'].' '.$uploadfile;
    }
}else {
    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)){
        echo 'upload dir does not exist '.getcwd().' '.$uploadfile.'\n';
    }
    if(!is_writable($uploaddir)) {
        echo 'Upload directory is not writable.'.'\n';
    }
}
```

Under all circumstances I get "error" returned with the two filenames. error.log shows nothing. root user has read/write to the directory and all parents.

Can you please point out the simple flaw in my logic. I would also appreciate it if this did not involve third party methods. There are valid reasons for not using AFNetworking in this case.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was NOT a problem with the code.....

The directory membersImages was somehow corrupt. permissions showed 776 and owner showed as root user, root user could CD into the directory, but a LS showed zero content. exiting and rmdir failed because directory was not empty. recursive delete worked, MKDIR and upload works.

Color me bizarred.....

Answer (score 0):

The upload path is wrong, depending on where your script is change

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/memberImages/';
```

To

```
$uploaddir = 'memberImages/';
```

Comment: my script is in /var/www/html/conAPI/ my memberImage directory is /var/www/html/memberImages/ I have tried the explicite /var/www/html/memberImages and I have also tried ../memberImages I pass the file_exits test and the is writable test, so the script sees the image directory and can write to it, the file has mass (about 85K) and exists in the tmp file space, but the move simply says error without an error.log entry.

Comment: @ChrisHardaker so you need `../memberImages/`